# Get-AzKeyVaultSecret cannot get plain text secret

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I used the syntax below to get the plain text of the secret in AZ powershell:

`Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'valt1' -Name 'url' -AsPlainText`

However, I got `[string]::Format`.

I also tried

`(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $mongoKeyVault -Name $backendRwUriName).SecretValue`,
but I got `System.Security.SecureString`

How can I get the actual secret string as shown in the portal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could get the desired results using the below command.

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "<VAULT_NAME>" -Name "<SECRET_NAME>" -AsPlainText
```

Unless your secret must be `[string]::Format` you wont be receiving it as the result.

Firstly, I have created my secret as below.

[image]

Below are the results I got using the above command.

[image]